# El capitan pololu isp dongle pgm03a not working anymore

Tags: serial-port, osx-elcapitan, disconnect

I have a Pololu PGM03A isp dongle to programm microcontrollers via avrdude. It worked great under Yosemite, but under El Capitan, it seems to disconnect and reconnect randomly every 1 - 5 sec. I can see this by the green status LED and in the terminal:

```
Macintosh:~ xxxxx$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.usbmodem00070153
/dev/cu.serial1         /dev/cu.usbmodem2169
/dev/cu.usbmodem00070151
Macintosh:~ xxxxx$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.usbmodem00070153
/dev/cu.serial1
Macintosh:~ xxxxx$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/cu.usbmodem00070153
/dev/cu.serial1         /dev/cu.usbmodem2177
/dev/cu.usbmodem00070151
```

As you can see, the usbmodem00070151 is there, then not, and then again available. The usbmodem00070153 belongs to the ISP Dongle too, but it provides an different feature than programming the microcontroller (it's an USART Port or something I think).

Edit: The latter modem now also disconnects.

When I try to flash the microcontroller, it sometimes manages it to write some bytes, but the time between 2 disconnects is to short to finish the job:

```
Writing | ########################                           | 47% 0.08s
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: Device not configured
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I too am having this exact problem since switching o El Capitan. Ended up buying a new programmer but that has made no difference. I also reinstalled the avrdude stack but that didn't fix it either. So I'm suspecting the USB driver. Not sure how to troubleshoot. More info here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=351999.0 Seems like software serial ports in general are affected.

Comment: I buyed the "mySmartUSB light" ISP dongle in the end, which works great.

Dongle: http://shop.myavr.de/Topseller/mySmartUSB%20light.htm?sp=article.sp.php&artID=200006
Driver: http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx